# finite additivity&countable additivity

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $\tau$ be a semialgebra of subsets of $\Omega$ and let P: $\tau\rightarrow [0,1]$, with $P(\Omega)=1$, and it satisfies finite additivity:
$P\big(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}D_i\big)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}P(D_i)$ for $D_1,..., D_n\in \tau$ disjoint, and $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}D_i\in \tau$. Suppose we also have for $A_1,..., A_n \in \tau$ such that $A_{n+1}\subseteq A_n$ and $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n=\emptyset$, and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(A_n)=0$. Then how can I show that P holds countable additivity property?

Comment: Sorry, what is a 'semialgebra' of sets?

Comment: it contains $\emptyset$ and $\Omega$, it is closed under finite intersection, and the complement of any element of $\tau$ is equal to a finite disjoint union of elements of $\tau$.

Comment: @Berci See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Measure_Theory/Basic_Structures_And_Definitions/Semialgebras,_Algebras_and_%CF%83-algebras

Answer (score 2):

The answer to user133834's question is no. Let $\Omega=[0,1] \cap Q$($Q$ denotes a set of all rational numbers) and $\tau$ be defined as follows:
$$\tau=\{\emptyset\}\cup\{ q:q \in [0,1]\cap Q\} \cup \{ [a,b]\cap Q :0\le a<b\le 1\}\cup 
$$
$$\{ [a,b[\cap Q :0\le a<b\le 1\}\cup\{ ]a,b]\cap Q : 0 \le a<b \le 1\}\cup
$$
$$\{ ]a,b[\cap Q :0\le a<b\le 1\}.$$ 
Let $P:\tau \to [0,1]$ be defined as follows:$P(\{q\})=0$ for $q \in  [0,1]\cap Q$ and $$P([a,b]\cap Q)= P([a,b]\cap Q)= P([a,b[\cap Q)= P(]a,b]\cap Q)= P(]a,b[\cap Q)= b-a.$$ Then $\tau$ is a semialgebra and $P$ satisfies all conditions above but $P$ is not countable additive.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A_i \cap A_j =\emptyset $ for $i\neq j ,$ Let $$B_j =\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \right)\setminus \left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{j} A_n \right). $$ 
Then $$0=\lim_{j\to\infty} P(B_j) =P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \right) -\lim_{j\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^j P(A_n ).$$

Comment: sorry how do you show that $B_j$ is in $\tau$?

Comment: I use the finite additivity property here $$P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^j A_n \right) =\sum_{n=1}^j P(A_n )$$